# How to install capistrano gem, version 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I'm trying to learn capistrano for my first Rails project. After finding conflicing advice between [the website](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/) and other online info, I realised version 3 had recently been released, and it's not backward compatible.

So, I've uninstalled v2, and am trying to install v3 via the command mentioned on the website:

```
gem install capistrano --pre --trust-policy HighSecurity
```

But I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unsigned gem
```

Ironically, the website says that if I get that error for some other gem:

> Then please complain to your Gem author, and have them start signing their Gems.

So, what should I do? Is it safe to install capistrano without the `--trust-policy` flag? Or would I be better off just using version 2 for now and waiting for the dust to settle before using version three? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try In Gemfile `gem "capistrano", "~> 3.0.0.pre14"` or `gem install capistrano -v 3.0.0pre14`

Comment: Better to use 2.15.5 as it is stable version but If you want it any how to use 3, then  just do what I say in above comment

Comment: OK thanks. The website gives the impression that v3 is stable, and that v2 is legacy.

Comment: Thank you for voting me on my comments ....can you please vote me up on my post? Thanks joshua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try In Gemfile
`gem "capistrano", "~> 3.0.0.pre14"`
or
`gem install capistrano -v 3.0.0.pre14`

Better to use `2.15.5` as it is stable and not a `pre`  `version` but If you want it any how to use 3, then just do what I say in above

Thanks

Comment: how does this avoid signed gem issues?